# Maven generated zip file contains old war file

Tags: java, maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I have a multi-module Maven projet, and I want to build a zip file containing all of the files to deliver on the production server, which means a war file and a bunch of shellscripts.

Here some extracts from my parent pom.xml:

```xml
    <modules>
        <module>an-fwk</module>
        <module>eloi-model</module>
        <module>eloi-service</module>
        <module>eloi-facade</module>
        <module>eloi-web</module>
    </modules>

    ...
    
    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.3</version>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>Génération du livrable 3/5(1) : assemblage de l'archive eloi-batch</id>
                                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptor>
                                        ${assembly.descriptor.dir}/eloi-batch.xml
                                    </descriptor>
                                    <finalName>eloi-batch</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/${livrable.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>Génération du livrable 3/5(2) : assemblage de l'archive publicationweb</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptor>
                                        ${assembly.descriptor.dir}/publicationweb.xml
                                    </descriptor>
                                    <finalName>publicationweb</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/${livrable.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>Génération du livrable 3/5(3) : assemblage de l'archive publicationReferentiel</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptor>
                                        ${assembly.descriptor.dir}/publicationReferentiel.xml
                                    </descriptor>
                                    <finalName>publicationReferentiel</finalName>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/${livrable.dir}</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <!-- Here I generate the zip file -->
                            <execution>
                                <id>Génération du livrable : Création du zip pour Artifactory</id>
                                <phase>post-site</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>${assembly.descriptor.dir}/zip.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/artifactory</outputDirectory>
                                    <finalName>${deliverable.file.name}</finalName>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

The war file is generated in the eloi-web project. So I have a problem, because parent pom.xml is executed first, so I actually get the my zip file, but with the old version of the war file, before building, and it crashes if I clean first. I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Make a separate module (xyz-zip) which should produce the zip file (maven-assembly-plugin execution into that module) and add dependencies to that mode you would like to have in the zip file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the zip assembly to the pom.xml of the eloi-web module. I tried that before, but got other issues because `${basedir}` is not the same directory in the module than in the parent. A colleague suggested to use `${basedir}/../`, which solved those issues. Not really elegant, but simple and efficient.

Comment: Do not use a path outside of your own module. Better separate the task and make a complete separate module for a single purpose... (separation of concern)...

Comment: If I add a separate module, it will also have its own basedir, so it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Using configuration with basedir etc. are usually wrong...